# How to save same figure many times?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to save a file for each iteration of the fgoalattain. I have it printing the figure each time just fine. But using the savefig function saves each iteration as the exact same name, which erases previous iterations figures. How do I generate a unique saved figure for each?

```
figure
%TEST diff 200, 100, 50 FOR TIMES
while diff > 200
    iterations = iterations +1;
    disp('running fgoalattain')
    xz = fgoalattain(obj_Func,xz,goal,weight,[],[],[],[],zeros(x3,x3),ones(x3,x3),[],Options);
    diff = sum(sum(abs(xz - a),2));
    pcolor(xz)
    drawnow

    savefig('iterpic.fig');
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to savefig is the file name, and since that's not changing, you're just overwriting the same file every time.

Try something like:

```
savefig(sprintf('interpic-%d.fig',iterations));
```

to append the iteration number to the file name.

Comment: I like to use the '%03d' (the '3' is just an example) format instead of '%d', so file names are zero padded and are shown sorted in a file explore/terminal.

Comment: @ItamarKatz You could even, in a `for` loop that is, set it to the maximum number of attainable digits (thus if you do 1247 calculations set it to `04%d`). Good tip! Tip for you: use 'backticks' for code formatting in comments (usually that's the key above tab)

Answer (score 1):

Simple: create unique filenames using a counter and [`sprintf`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html)

```
figure
%TEST diff 200, 100, 50 FOR TIMES
kk = 1; %//counter of files
while diff > 200
    iterations = iterations +1;
    disp('running fgoalattain')
    xz = fgoalattain(obj_Func,xz,goal,weight,[],[],[],[],zeros(x3,x3),ones(x3,x3),[],Options);
    diff = sum(sum(abs(xz - a),2));
    pcolor(xz)
    drawnow
    kk = kk+1;
    savefilename = sprintf('interpic%d.fig',kk); %//get filename
    savefig(savefilename);
end
```

`sprintf` generates a string based on the format specified, i.e. `interpic%d.fig` in this case. The `%d` is an argument to call a variable and represent it as an integer, which is after the comma, being `kk` in this case.